# Random points in 2-sphere

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Say we have the PDF of uniformly picking a random point in the unit $2$-sphere, with distance from origin of the point being $r$, given as
$$
f_R(r) = \begin{cases}
    3r^2 & 0 \leq r \leq 1 \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
We then want to extend this to n points. How would I find the distributions of $X$, where $X$ is the second furthest point from the origin of these $n$ points? I imagine it is something along the lines of considering spheres within the sphere, but this isn't getting me anywhere.

Comment: A sphere is just smoke and mirrors. Essentially, you have $n$ i.i.d. random values with known distribution, and now want to derive the distributions of such values as _"second greatest of $n$"_. Well, the answer is known and relatively simple.

Answer (score 3):

Since we are interested in the distance from the origin and since the probability on the sphere of fixed radius $r$ is uniform, then we can simply consider the i.i.d. random variables $R_i\in[0,1]$ with PDF:
$$
f_{R_i}(r) = \begin{cases}3r^2 \mbox{ if $0\leq r\leq 1$} \\ 0 \mbox{ otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
and CDF:
$$
F_{R_i}(t) = \begin{cases} 0 \mbox{  if $t<0$}\\
t^3 \mbox{ if $0\leq t\leq 1$} \\ 1\mbox{  if $t>1$} \end{cases}
$$

We want to calculate the distribution of $R_{(n-1)}$ which is the second largest value among the $\{R_i\}_{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}}$.
We can proceed with an argument which is often used in statistics while calculating the $j$-th ordinal statistic:

Suppose there is an interval $(x,x+dx)$ which contains only the second largest value $R_{(n-1)}$. So $n-2$ among the $R_i$ are smaller than $x$ and only one of them is bigger than $x+dx$. So, using the multinomial distribution:

$$
P(x<R_{(n-1)}<x+dx) = \frac{n!}{(n-2)!\cdot 1!\cdot 1!}(P(R < x))^{n-2}P(x < R < x+dx )P(R > x+dx)
$$
since the $R_i$ are i.i.d. random variables. Then we divide by $dx$ as follows:
$$
\frac{P(x<R_{(n-1)}<x+dx)}{dx} = n(n-1)[F_R(x)]^{n-2}\frac{F_R(x+dx)-F_R(x)}{dx}[1-F_R(x+dx)]
$$
Taking the limit as $dx\to 0$ we obtain:
$$
f_{R_{(n-1)}}(x) = \lim_{dx\to 0} n(n-1)[F_R(x)]^{n-2}\frac{F_R(x+dx)-F_R(x)}{dx}[1-F_R(x+dx)]
$$
and since the derivative of the CDF is the PDF we have that:
$$
f_{R_{(n-1)}}(x) = n(n-1)[F_R(x)]^{n-2}f_R(x)[1-F_R(x)] = n(n-1)x^{3(n-2)}3x^2(1-x^3)
$$
And here it is! The PDF of the second further distance from the origin in a sample of $n$ i.i.d. random variables $R_i$ defined as above.

Of course $f_{R_{(n-1)}}(r)$ is defined for $r\in[0,1]$.